# Firebase custom events not showing on console events tab

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-analytics

I have some custom events sent to Firebase Analytics. I can see them sending in app logs in Xcode, I can see them in debug view and stream view but they are missing from events tab. What am I doing wrong? What is missing in my configuration? I did wait some hours to see if it will appear but didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so turns out that custom events take huge time to be processed by Firebase.